# PDO Fetch IMSSP Invalid Type

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, pdo

Here is my Problem.

I'am trying to do this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.V_Daten_GekPatrone ORDER BY Tagesnummer DESC ";
$sql = $conn->query($query);
try
{
    while ($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        //Do Something.....
    }
} catch (Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
    var_dump($e);
}
```

What i get is for the Exeption Message:

> SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: Invalid type.

and for the Var_Dump:

```
object(PDOException)[9]
  protected 'message' => string 'SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: Invalid type.' (length=30)
  private 'string' (Exception) => string '' (length=0)
  protected 'code' => string 'IMSSP' (length=5)
  protected 'file' => string 'H:\xampp\htdocs\Projekte\munition\test.php' (length=42)
  protected 'line' => int 24
  private 'trace' (Exception) => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=5)
          'file' => string 'H:\xampp\htdocs\Projekte\munition\test.php' (length=42)
          'line' => int 0
          'function' => string 'fetch' (length=5)
          'class' => string 'PDOStatement' (length=12)
          'type' => string '->' (length=2)
  private 'previous' (Exception) => 
    object(PDOException)[8]
      protected 'message' => string 'SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: Invalid type.' (length=30)
      private 'string' (Exception) => string '' (length=0)
      protected 'code' => string 'IMSSP' (length=5)
      protected 'file' => string 'H:\xampp\htdocs\Projekte\munition\test.php' (length=42)
      protected 'line' => int 24
      private 'trace' (Exception) => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            array (size=5)
              ...
      private 'previous' (Exception) => 
        object(PDOException)[7]
          protected 'message' => string 'SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: Invalid type.' (length=30)
          private 'string' (Exception) => string '' (length=0)
          protected 'code' => string 'IMSSP' (length=5)
          protected 'file' => string 'H:\xampp\htdocs\Projekte\munition\test.php' (length=42)
          protected 'line' => int 24
          private 'trace' (Exception) => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          private 'previous' (Exception) => 
            object(PDOException)[6]
              ...
          public 'errorInfo' => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
      public 'errorInfo' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string 'IMSSP' (length=5)
          1 => int -27
          2 => string 'Invalid type.' (length=13)
  public 'errorInfo' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'IMSSP' (length=5)
      1 => int -27
      2 => string 'Invalid type.' (length=13)
```

I the statement runs with out a problem on the SQL-Server here are the first 2 results:

```
ID  Tagesnummer Menge       Zustand           Hersteller     Gewichtsveraenderung   Temp    Bemerkung   Luftfeuch   Luftdruck
5      9338014    568   verschossen   CIS State Arsenals                   -23       18         NULL          40          968
5      9338013    568   verschossen   CIS State Arsenals                   -23       18         NULL          43          968
```

I hava another request just like it on the same Page and it runs without Problem too.

Which means my DB Connection is ok.

So what am I doing wrong with this one?
From the Execption i would say that the Statment($query) isn't passed on but how is that possible?

Any Ideas? 
While googeling i found [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-query.php#112287) look at the first User Contributed Notes. But i checked but no such errors in code. But wanted to leave this here since there is not much outthere for this error Type.

I also checked that $sql is not false so the query() went through.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `$query` statement to something like:

```
$query = "SELECT CAST(col1 AS VARCHAR(255)), CAST(col2 AS VARCHAR(255)), CAST(col3 AS VARCHAR(255)) FROM dbo.V_Daten_GekPatrone ORDER BY Tagesnummer DESC";
```

Casting the columns being selected as `varchar` solved a similar issue for me when I was getting the same error i.e.

> SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: Invalid type.